# Converting JSON inside PostgreSQL

Tags: php, json, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have to prepare a database which contains many tables and columns. As a input I will receive JSON data and here is the question, is it posiible to convert JSON data using only functions inside postgresql and do CRUD operations on database? And Is it a good approach? Normally I would write a php server application to handle and convert JSON data however this is the project for my studies and my teacher highly insists on using only functions inside postgresql if it's possible, so is it? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all CRUD operations on JSON data internally, within the database... but this is not a good approach to store JSON and read from it frequently. If you meant to receive JSON data and convert it to native data types - tables and columns - then it's perfectly ok and you can do virtually everything using internal database functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for answer, have you ever seen someone doing something like that, got any examples, directions, which functions suit best?